# Magento test automation framework ambiguity

Tags: magento-1.4, testing, automation

We are using `Magento 1.4` at the moment to develop an e-commerce website. I don't know why we are using old version, but we are.

My task is to set up some automation tests. If possible the idea is to use these tests across different websites which also have been built using `Magento 1.4`.

I am completely new to Magento. I did some research, found some good links for installation. I could not find this information though.

Can you please answer the below questions and help me please?

1. [taf](https://github.com/magento/taf) is the link I found for test automation framework. This does not come with prewritten regression tests. Is that correct? Is this compatible with `Magento 1.4`?

I found that the above repo is deprecated now and there is a new one being maintained [mtf](https://github.com/magento/mtf). On seeing the installation prerequisites ([www.github.com/magento/mtf/blob/master/docs/install-config.md](http://www.github.com/magento/mtf/blob/master/docs/install-config.md)) of this it says  Magento 2 is a must.

I am confused now. I must to use `Magento 1.4`. Which automation framework can I use? Any ideas? Preferably I am looking for one which has some pre-written testcases for Magento, so that it easier to start off with and build atop.

To install and run Magento I found this as the best link so far. ([www.dhmedia.com.au/article/how-install-and-run-magento-test-automation-framework](http://www.dhmedia.com.au/article/how-install-and-run-magento-test-automation-framework)). If you have come across something else better please share.

Overall, is it any better and easier to just forget about MTAF and write own automation tests using say testng(Java) or PHPUnit and selenium? I am talking about user-journey tests on e-commerce platform like Placing an order, Browsing through, Creating wishlist, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, The Magento Test Automation Framework was built for Magento 1.5-1.7.  The Magento Testing Framework is for Magento 2.x.  That means that there is a funny little section of the Magento 1.x world that cannot properly leverage a full testing framework.

These are the areas of unit and functional testing.  There are others out there, but these are the main ones.  If there are additional ones people wish to see, message me and I'll add them.

## Testing Framework Support for Magento

**Ecomdev PHPUnit**

```
Magento Support: 1.4 - 1.9
Coverage: Unit Tests
Tests Written?: No
Link: https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit
```

**Magento Test Automation Framework**

```
Magento Support: 1.5 - 1.7 (Official) 1.8 - 1.9 (Unofficial, no tests for new features)
Coverage: Unit and Functional Tests
Tests Written?: Yes
Link: https://github.com/magento/taf
```

**Magento Testing Framework**

```
Magento Support: 2.x
Coverage: Unit Test (Functional to come)
Tests Written? Yes
Link: https://github.com/magento/mtf
```

## Can My Magento Be Tested?

This table can give a quick view of what testing support you have available to you.

Please forgive the archaic table.  SO doesn't support table markdown (that I'm aware of).  I had to use an image.

[image: Magento Test Coverage Table]

Comment: Since the MTAF itself is Selenium based you can write your own tests based on selenium or any other technology for functional tests (e.g. Dalekjs, sample Magento-test suite can be found here: https://github.com/luemic/magento-dalekjs). If there's a need for unit testing then you can use the EcomDev_PHPUnit framework.

Comment: @Ryan street, Michael  . Thank you for your answers. 

Now regarding enterprise edition, does Magento enterprise edition 1.14 have pre written functional automation tests? 

My other question is isn't it enough I do end-to-end user journey tests like logging in, placing order, payment for order, cancel order, etc .. which will implicitly test the units(code) underneath from a QA tester point of view?

I am also thinking if I don't use Magento framework I will be able to use the same automation tests for some other store which doesn't use Magento at all.

Share your thoughts.

Comment: In TAF (github.com/magento/taf) there are only about 5 pre written tests. I don't see anymore functional tests. Am I right? So, it is mostly a framework to build onto then and not really a testsuite which will cover many functional tests like placing an order etc.

Comment: @JayK, unfortunately the TAF doesn't have tests for 1.14.  Since it was deprecated in CE 1.7, it only has tests up to EE1.12 (equivalent).

Comment: @Ryan, Thanks again for that. I was wondering if I can use Magento 2.x tests on Magento 1.14, assuming there are no major changes in 2.x?

Comment: @JayK, sorry No.  Magento 2.x is a much different platform than Magento 1.x. The changes are pretty drastic.

Comment: @RyanStreet is this answer still relevant? [The MTF documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_installation.html) seems to suggest that it can be used on Magento 1.x

Comment: @RobbieAverill, yes it is still relevant according to my latest readings.  The MTF link you provided is for M2 installations.

Comment: @RyanStreet I know, but it says it can be used on M1 also which suggests the MTAF might be deprecated in its favour

Comment: @RobbieAverill you are correct!  They do cover tests from M1 now.  I just read the introduction.  I'll update my answer.  Thanks for the update!